# How to set up JupyterHub/JupyterLab with different conda environments correctly?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

A little background: I want to use JupyterHub/JupterLab to allow my students to design notebooks in a collaborative manner. In principle, I have a JupyterLab running with collaboration which seems to work. However, from what I can tell, JupyterLab does not come with user management, right? So anyone with the link and the password can open a notebook and edit it, right?

I therefore also installed JupyterHub which supports user management based on system user accounts, which seems fine enough. JupterHub is running, but not in a collaborative manner. I think I'm just too confused about how these work together. For example, I can open the same notebook on 2 different machines using either JupyterHub or JupyterLab, but Real-Time Collaboration (RTC) only works with JupyterLab.

I also don't know how to integrate this correctly with virtual environments in conda. It seems I have JupyterLab installed in all my current environments, e.g.,

```
./lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
./envs/env_a/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
./envs/env_b/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
```

But JupyterHub inly in the "base" environment:

```
./bin/jupyterhub
./lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub
./share/jupyterhub
./pkgs/jupyterhub-3.1.0-py39h06a4308_0/bin/jupyterhub
./pkgs/jupyterhub-3.1.0-py39h06a4308_0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterhub
./pkgs/jupyterhub-3.1.0-py39h06a4308_0/share/jupyterhub
```

So things kind of work, I'm not sure if this is done properly. Is it correct to say the starting JupyterHub in the "base" environment is using the JupyterLab installation in the "base" environment? Do I need a JupyterHub installation for each conda environment?

I generally only find basic information about the installation, but not really how this all works together, particularly when having multiple conda environments? That being said, within JupyterHub and JupyterLab, I see all environments and I can change the kernels for a notebook.

Comment: If you can select the environment for jupyterLab, in jupyterHub, the environments should not be the issue. You can install jupyterLab on `base` just to be sure, however.

Comment: I’m not aware of a way to co-edit in real time with user management. May be a new feature though. For more real time feedback on lots of questions I’d actually go to the jupyter discord or gitter channels linked to on the [community engagement page of the jupyterhub docs](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contributing/community.html) - there are lots of active users there who will readily help a teacher setting this up for a classroom.